# Exporting 6 WAV files from 5.1 surround AAC using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, split, export, wav, surround

I'm trying to export 6 WAV files from a 5.1 surround AAC audio file using ffmpeg using this code

```
ffmpeg -i "input.aac" -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR]" -map "[FL]" front_left.wav -map "[FR]" front_right.wav -map "[FC]" front_center.wav -map "[LFE]" lfe.wav -map "[BL]" back_left.wav -map "[BR]" back_right.wav
```

but I receive this error

```
[aac @ 000001f352b802c0] Scalefactor (256) out of range.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
input.aac: Invalid data found when processing input
size=     198kB time=00:00:02.11 bitrate= 768.4kbits/s speed=  52x
video:0kB audio:1188kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

The problem seems to be "Scalefactor (256) out of range." and I've googled it and looked through the ffmpeg documentation, but I can't seem to find any solution to my problem.
That's why I'm asking you to help me.
It would be so kind of you to help me in this journey of exporting surround sound to multiple files.

Comment: The decoder found some invalid data in the bitstream and has bailed out. Do you have libfdk_aac linked in your ffmpeg build?

Comment: If you don't have libfdk_aac support, and are unable to compile ffmpeg with libfdk_aac, then share the file if you can and one of us can test it with libfdk_aac.